# how to add minimize button in PYQT6

Tags: pyqt, pyqt6

I try to add a minimize button in QDialog, but I get error:
AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'WindowMinimizeButtonHint'

```
class MyWidget(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
        self.setWindowTitle("My QDialog")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PyQt6 you can no longer use short-form names for enum members. You have to include the enum name. In this case `WindowType`

```
self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowType.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
```

Comment: thank you, when I use this command, it works well.